# Page content is larger than the screen width

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind css to build a website but my page content is increasing the screen width. I have checked that the box-sizing is set to border-box and margin, padding for body is set to 0 too but this issue still occurs.

How do i solve this issue?

Navbar html:-

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="./assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/images/paper.png">
</head>
<body class="bg-sky-500 overflow-x-hidden w-full">
  <nav class="px-6 md:px-12 py-1.5 md:py-2.5 bg-yellow-400 m-3 md:m-5 rounded-xl shadow-md shadow-sky-600 flex absolute z-50 top-0 right-0 left-0 w-full">
    <img src="./assets/images/icon.png" alt="icon" class="w-[14%] sm:w-[6.5%] md:w-[4.2%] hidden xs:block" />
    <p class="font-semibold text-gray-50 font-main m-auto text-xs sm:text-base md:text-lg tracking-wider">ROCK PAPER SCISSOR</p>
  </nav>
  <div class="mb-24 md:mb-0 mt-[14rem] md:mt-0 md:!my-56 flex mx-5 md:mx-0 relative w-full">
    <div class="md:ml-32 mt-6 md:mt-12 font-main w-full md:w-2/6 mr-auto">
      <div class="mb-2.5 h-[36px] md:h-[60px]">
        <p class="text-4xl md:text-6xl text-yellow-400 font-bold drop-shadow-md" id="rpsText">ROCK</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline-block w-full">
        <p class="text-sm md:text-lg text-gray-50 mb-6">Online rock paper scissor game, create a room or join one to play with your friends!</p>
        <div class="inline-flex w-full gap-3 flex-wrap">
          <button class="rounded-md px-3 md:px-5 py-1.5 md:py-2 bg-yellow-400 hover:shadow-xl shadow-sky-700 duration-300 ease-in-out font-bold font-main text-stone-800 text-xs md:text-sm w-full md:mx-auto">CREATE ROOM</button>
          <button class="rounded-md px-3 md:px-5 py-1.5 md:py-2 bg-yellow-400 hover:shadow-xl shadow-sky-700 duration-300 ease-in-out font-bold font-main text-stone-800 text-xs md:text-sm w-full md:mx-auto">JOIN ROOM</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="md:mr-24 absolute md:relative -top-24 sm:-top-28 md:top-0 -right-14 w-[50%] sm:w-[40%] md:w-[30%]">
      <img src="./assets/images/rock.png" alt="rockImg" id="rockImg" class="w-[64%] drop-shadow-lg rpsImage !opacity-100" />
      <img src="./assets/images/paper.png" alt="paperImg" id="paperImg" class="w-[64%] drop-shadow-lg rpsImage" />
      <img src="./assets/images/scissor.png" alt="scissorImg" id="scissorImg" class="w-[64%] drop-shadow-lg rpsImage" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-500 h-72 mt-60 mx-3 md:mx-44 rounded-xl p-4 mb-44">
    <p class="mx-auto text-xl font-bold text-stone-800 font-main text-center drop-shadow-md">ABOUT US</p>
  </div>
  <script src="./assets/js/rpsHero.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create this code  in codesandbox / fiddle /codepen or any development environment of your choice

Comment: @IAMSTR if you just want to know how the page looks - https://rps.amannn.tk/ 
If not then let me know ill share a codepen

Comment: is it that you want the site to look like the site you just shared ,the code you shared and the site have some subtle differences just share a codepen a mockup of how you want the site to look like

Comment: @IAMSTR https://codepen.io/astrexxx/pen/Expparx here's the codepen and yes that's how i want it to look.

Comment: @RenevanderLende margin bottom is adding to width ?

Comment: what element is breaking your design? can you specify the problem you face? is it the nav bar ? is it supposed to be the same width as the content in the footer and the main content